# How to calculate angle between two objects in orbit

Tags: physics

So I have 2 objects in orbit around the same body, and I have all the orbital elements associated with each body. How do I calculate the angle between them both or figure out when they are a certain angle apart using only the all the orbital elements I have?

Comment: This seems like a question in celestial mechanics, not mathematics *per se*.  There are standard formulas for computing the rectangular coordinates of each of the orbiting objects.  Once you know the distances between each of the objects, I suppose you can use the law of cosines to obtain the angle subtended by the two objects from the central body: $\cos C = \frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$.

Comment: Law of Cosines would be helpful here

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're talking about Newtonian mechanics with only one spherical body of non-negligible mass (let's say the Sun), and the others in elliptical orbits.  Now unfortunately if these ellipses are not circles the position as a function of time is not available in "closed form": you have to [solve an equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit)

$$ t = \dfrac{a^{3/2}}{\mu^{1/2}} (E - e \sin(E)) $$

to get the eccentric anomaly $E$ as a function of time $t$, and then the coordinates of the body can be obtained from that.  However, if the eccentricity $e$ is small, this is well approximated by a series in powers of $e$.

Once you have the positions, you get the angle using the Law of Cosines, as others have mentioned.